# Notepad++ Associate custom ext for use by ctags

Tags: notepad++, ctags

I use .pkb and pkh extensions for PL/SQL files (rather than .sql). I have already associated .pkb and .pkh extension in the langs.xml (Styler Config) so that Notepad++ recognizes the syntax highlight to use when I open pkb and pkh files (the syntax highlighting would be the same as for sql ext).
Now the problem is that I cannot use plugins that parse code using ctags (like SourceCookifier, OpenCtag,GtagSearch) because these plugins do not recognize the pkb and pkh extension. THe only way I could use them is to change my file to sql and when done change to the pkh or pkb ext.

Is there any config that could make ctags based plugin work with non-sql ext? I tried changing various config for the plugins but did not succeed in making them work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SourceCookifier has an option to associate new file extensions to any of the pre-defined languages.

Menu Plugins -> SourceCookifier -> Language Settings. Choose SQL from the drop down, and add .pkb and .pkh to the second column.

Comment: Installing SourceCookifier and adding extensions does not activate syntax highlighting for those for me. What step am I missing?

Comment: @gentlesea To add syntax highlighting to notepad, you must add it in the Style Configurator plugin for that text type. So for SQL you'd add a user ext of "pkh" or "pkb". Without the quotes. The menu can be found in [Settings -> Style Configurator].

Answer (score 0):

Use NppCCompletionPlugin for Notepad++. (version 1.17 or above)

Then change the setting file **NppCCompletionPlugin.ini** to:

```
--fields=-afiklmnSzt+sK --c-kinds=+lp --langmap=sql:+.pkb --langmap=sql:+.pkh --excmd=number -f`
```

Then regenerate the tags files.

Comment: I can only find a version without NppCCompletionPlugin.ini here: http://freeweb.siol.net/rmihor/NppCCompletionPlugin.zip